# Vertical Axis in chart repeating values -SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services

This is my data:

```
Year /  Month / Sales 
2012 /  1 / 2496496.82 
2011 /  1 / 2618210.62
2012 /  2 / 2451754.51 
2011 /  2 / 2268699.08 
2011 /  3 / 2810107.42
2012 /  3 / 2621037.55
```

Serie label properties: Currency, show values in Millions, use 1000 separators, decimal place 2

vertical axis properties: minimun auto, maximun auto, interval auto, interval type auto

and this is what a got in vertical axis:

```
3
3
2
2
1
1
0
```

The report showing duplicated values in Y-axis, How can i get rid of the repeating values 3 3 2 2 1 1 ??

I hope someone has the answer, thank you

Comment: if you see the values in the vertical axis, they are duplicated: 3,3,2,2,1,1......... how can I fix this?

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to clarify it.

Comment: You still need to work a bit on the question imho. A few things to improve: there's currently no "flow" in the question (it doesn't read very well), partially because of weird/missing interpunction and capitalization. In addition it helps if you explain what you've tried, and why it didn't work. Finally, you seem to be omitting several details (about your report structure, for one). *Try to make it as easy as possible for us to answer your question.*

Comment: "A picture is worth a thousand words", please see this link with my final report http://i48.tinypic.com/x2022o.jpg, this is how it looks like now

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is Y - Axis showing you repeated numbers. Actual issue is it is not showing the decimal places there that means

3 
3 
2 
2 
1 
1 
0

should be like follow

3.5 
3.0 
2.5 
2.0 
1.5 
1.0 
0.0

But it doesn't show decimal places.

To resolve this go to the **"Vertical Axis Properties"** -> **Number** tab -> Choose the **Category** as **"Default"**  while keeping **Minimum, Maximum, Interval and Interval Type = Auto** in the **Axis Option** tab.